# Delete all except two folders with .bat file

Tags: batch-file

**Batch**

```
@echo off
set folder="c:\FTP\"
set keep="keep1"
set keeptwo="keep2"

cd /d %folder%

for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (
    if /i "%%~ni" NEQ %keep% if /i "%%~ni" NEQ %keeptwo% (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
)

pause
```

**Situation**

- folder1/file1.txt
- folder2/file1.txt
- keep1/file1.txt
- keep2/file1.txt
- file1.txt

**Expected result**

I need to keep "keep1" and "keep2" folders and all included files, but "folder1" and "folder2" and "file1.txt" with all subdirectories and files must be deleted.

**Current result**

It removes all files in all folders, removes "folder1" and "folder2", and keeps "keep1" and "keep2"

Any clue what I'm missing.

Comment: I've just tried your code and it did not removed the files from folder keep1 and keep2, so it looks like it's working fine.

Comment: Did you use the same file in all folders and root? If I put different files, it works fine. If I use same files, it deletes them all.

Comment: I used the same (empty) file all over the place.

Comment: You can't use the `/S` option with the `DELETE` command.  That means to delete the file from the current directory and all subdirectories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the `/S` option with the `DELETE` command as that will delete the file in the current directory and all subdirectories.

Regardless of that, this is how I would accomplish the task so that you don't get the error from the `RMDIR` command.  I use an `IF EXIST` command to determine if it is a file or directory.

```
@echo off
set "folder=c:\FTP\"
set "keep=keep1"
set "keeptwo=keep2"

cd /d %folder%

for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /b') do (
    if /I NOT "%%G"=="%keep%" (
        if /I NOT "%%G"=="%keeptwo%" (
            REM check if it is a directory or file
            IF EXIST "%%G\" (
                rmdir "%%G" /s /q
            ) else (
                del "%%G" /q
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: works perfectly, im using it for a visual studio post-build event and it cleans up all the output junk in my release dir! life saver

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that this is what you wanted to do:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "folder=C:\FTP"
Set "keep=keep1"
Set "keeptwo=keep2"

CD /D "%folder%" 2>Nul || Exit /B
Del /F/A/Q *
For /D %%A In (*) Do If /I Not "%%A"=="%keep%" If /I Not "%%A"=="%keep2%" RD /S/Q "%%A"
Pause
```